# Getting aw snap error in Chrome and Firefox in Angular 5 app

Tags: angular, angular5

I am getting aw snap error page at unexpected times in my Angular 5 app. Is there any fix for that?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off, and back on again?

Comment: turn off what?I am getting this error in every instance of chrome.

Comment: whats aw snap?.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Comment: @Akshay did you fix it??? I am also facing same issue for Angular 6 app

Comment: Not yet.Looking forward for the solution

Answer (score 5):

This is late but it may useful for someone in the future
The problem is, I called the own selector in the HTML file...
For ex.,
inside the shopping-list.component.html I called the same html component selector  again mentioned below.so it crashes.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <app-shopping-list></app-shopping-list>
        <p>The list</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

so check that you are calling the same selector file inside html and remove that from html

Comment: this is not perfect answer but it helped me to resolve my issue.

Comment: why this is not a perfect answer?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was large number of DOM nodes and opening developer tools.

I don't know about memory usage, but my js heap size was 13.5 MB sometimes getting upto 20MBs.